# Accessing database data in Laravel Spark kiosk settings

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

I have added a new page under kiosk settings under API keys. On my new panel I have a select box and I need to populate it with values from a database table.

I'm not sure how to best do this. There seems to be this Spark.state object where the user and team values are put, so if I guess this might be a place.

Or else I load it with Ajax???

This is so easy in normal Laravel I just pass the object from the controller to the view and build the box on the blade view.

Am I missing something? How would i best do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way Spark is built with inline-templates, you can still use blade like normal.

You've created the new link in the menu sidebar, so now copy what the other settings are doing by having a tabcard be displayed when the menu item is clicked.

I recommend creating a new blade file for your new menu item and including it in that tabcard. You'll see some examples in the Spark settings blade file. Because you're using blade to render it, you don't need to load anything through AJAX.